# CSS transform z-index issues

Tags: css, z-index, transform

When opening the navigation dropdown, the transformed fonts in the sidebar on the right sidebar: "UNSERE HEIMSPIELE 2014",... and so on in [kassel-titans.de](http://kassel-titans.de/) are displayed over the navigation dropdown.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that by declaring top: 16px for .GDtitans, you're giving that element a position. #megaMenu has position: relative, but neither have a z-index set. Since the .GDtitan elements occur later in the document, they overlap #megaMenu.

Try adding a z-index to both, something like:

```
#megaMenu {
  z-index: 20;
}
.GDtitan {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Now #megaMenu will have a higher z-index, and will overlap everything else.

Answer (score 0):

By Removing below (or using desired value)

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

From your GDtitans class and it will solve your problem.

Here you can find more explanation on that: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/

Comment: doesnt work in chrome, and the font smoothing disappers when i remove the abovementioned.

Answer (score -1):

you should but z-index on your navigation div not on ul only

```
div#navigation{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

that should work fine